# Why it echo the whole form again?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

My problem is when the data  is submitted and saved using ajax it gives the response text and after that it echo the whole form again.

example:

```
 this is a form  
 submit button save button  
 When response received from ajax the page looks like this..

  this is a form
  ajax response..

  this form again
  submit button save button
  submit button save button
```

When this button is called

```
<div id="output"></div>
<button type="button" onClick="save()">Save to drafts</button>
```

it calls an ajax function to execute

```
function save(){
var save = new XMLHttpRequest;
var url = "panel.php";
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var page = document.getElementById("page").value;
var cont = document.getElementById("cont").value;
var send = "name="+name+"&page="+page+"&cont="+cont+"&call=yes";
save.open("POST", url, true);
save.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
save.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(save.readyState == 4 && save.status == 200){
        var output = save.responseText;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    }
}
save.send(send);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "saving.... Please wait..";
```

}

My php script just echo a string saved or not saved.

Comment: I suggest you use jquery and save your time

Comment: You are echoing the output of ajax response only in part of page(may be) i.e element with id output so the form will still remain unless output is the id of body

Comment: I didn't got you can you explain it.. more detialed..

Comment: id output is of div element

Comment: That's the reason. When you use ajax the page is not refreshed, Only a part of page is changed in you case div.So the output of php page is placed in div leaving the other part of page intact

Comment: But why it is then display my form double times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `panel.php` is also the page that has the form in the first place.

Make sure you `die()` after outputting your AJAX response, otherwise it will continue happily along outputting anything else on the page - in this case, your form.

Comment: hmm. It helped but i have included a file on top of page now it is echoing that out.. i used exit(); in php after echo statement

Comment: Why don't you put your AJAX files separate from your non-AJAX files? Much easier!